# Local push notifications not working on live app

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I had an game created, when they send me version via test flight (outside of itunes connect) it works correctly and i get local push notifications - also the prompt asking if i want to allow push notifications.

However, when the game is uploaded to itunes connect and i download from there the local push notifications do not work, i also do not receive a message asking for permission to allow notifications from this game.

Any idea on why it works outside itunes connect but not when downloading from appstore or prerelease from itunes.?

Notification appears to be raised by:

```
- (void) sendLocalReminder:(NSDate *)date  Type:(NSString*)type Alert:(NSString *)title{
    // some code ...
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;

    localNotif.fireDate = date;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"Reminder", nil);
    localNotif.alertBody = title;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:type forKey:@"lid"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

}

-(void)notifyScratch
{
    [self sendLocalReminder:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:TIME_LIFE_BONUS] Type:LNT_SCRATCH_CARD Alert:LNM_SCRATCH_CARD];
}
```

AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  
//  
//
//  Created by HuangYinHui on 11/12/14.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2014. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef  _APP_DELEGATE_H_
#define  _APP_DELEGATE_H_

#include "CCApplication.h"

/**
@brief    The cocos2d Application.

The reason to implement with private inheritance is to hide some interface details of CCDirector.
*/
class  AppDelegate : private cocos2d::CCApplication
{
public:
    AppDelegate();
    virtual ~AppDelegate();

    /**
    @brief    Implement CCDirector and CCScene init code here.
    @return true    Initialize success, app continue.
    @return false   Initialize failed, app terminate.
    */
    virtual bool applicationDidFinishLaunching();

    /**
    @brief  The function is called when the application enters the background
    @param  the pointer of the application instance
    */
    virtual void applicationDidEnterBackground();

    /**
    @brief  The function is called when the application enters the foreground
    @param  the pointer of the application instance
    */
    virtual void applicationWillEnterForeground();
};

#endif // _APP_DELEGATE_H_
```

AppDelegate.cpp

```
//  Created by HuangYinHui on 11/12/14.
//  Copyright __MyCompanyName__ 2014. All rights reserved.
//

#include "AppDelegate.h"

#include "GameUtils/GameConfig.h"

#include "GameScene/LoadingScene.h"
//#include "GameScene/MainMenuScene.h"
//#include "GameScene/ScratchCardsScene.h"
//#include "GameScene/DialogBoxScene.h"
//#include "GameScene/BuyCoinsScene.h"
#include "GameScene/GameScene.h"
//#include "GameScene/HowToPlayScene.h"
//#include "GameScene/GameEndScene.h"

USING_NS_CC;
using namespace CocosDenshion;

AppDelegate::AppDelegate()
{

}

AppDelegate::~AppDelegate()
{
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{
    // initialize director
    CCDirector *pDirector = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    pDirector->setOpenGLView(CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView());

    // turn on display FPS
    pDirector->setDisplayStats(false);

    // set FPS. the default value is 1.0/60 if you don't call this
    pDirector->setAnimationInterval(1.0 / 60);

    loadGameInfo();
    // create a scene. it's an autorelease object
    CCScene *pScene = LoadingScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = MainMenuScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = ScratchCardsScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = DialogBoxScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = BuyCoinsScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = GameScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = HowToPlayScene::scene();
//    CCScene *pScene = GameEndScene::scene();

    // run
    pDirector->runWithScene(pScene);

    return true;
}

// This function will be called when the app is inactive. When comes a phone call,it's be invoked too
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground()
{
//    CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification(EVENT_COME_TO_BACKGROUND, NULL);
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();
    SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
    SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseAllEffects();
}

// this function will be called when the app is active again
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()
{
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();
    SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
    SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeAllEffects();

#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM==CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
    if (g_pGameScene)
        g_pGameScene->listenToForeground(NULL);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Not without posting some code on how they have implemented local notifications

Comment: -(void)notifyScratch
{
    [self sendLocalReminder:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:TIME_LIFE_BONUS] Type:LNT_SCRATCH_CARD Alert:LNM_SCRATCH_CARD];
}

Comment: Is that in your view? What about the delegate to register your notifications? Trying to establish if code is correct first of all

Comment: No it is in a file called AppController.mm  - cocos2d application

Comment: The app needs to register for its local notifications, which is not shown in your code (usually in appdelegate), if you have previously allowed access to it thats why its not asking you for permission to show local notifications again

Comment: Yes i allowed it one time on one device and it not longer asks me for permission. 

But the same code (my developer says) when uploaded to a app store notifications not work.

I will add appdelegate code now.